# VBA ShellWait API 32 and 64 bit compatibility

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have the following [code](http://access.mvps.org/access/api/api0004.htm) that I tried to make compatible for 32 and 64 bit (Access 2010+).

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

'This code was originally written by Terry Kreft.
'It is not to be altered or distributed,
'except as part of an application.
'You are free to use it in any application,
'provided the copyright notice is left unchanged.
'
'Code Courtesy of
'Terry Kreft
Private Const STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW& = &H1
Private Const NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS = &H20&
Private Const INFINITE = -1&

Private Type STARTUPINFO
    cb As Long
    lpReserved As String
    lpDesktop As String
    lpTitle As String
    dwX As Long
    dwY As Long
    dwXSize As Long
    dwYSize As Long
    dwXCountChars As Long
    dwYCountChars As Long
    dwFillAttribute As Long
    dwFlags As Long
    wShowWindow As Integer
    cbReserved2 As Integer
    lpReserved2 As Long
    hStdInput As LongPtr
    hStdOutput As LongPtr
    hStdError As LongPtr
End Type

Private Type PROCESS_INFORMATION
    hProcess As LongPtr
    hThread As LongPtr
    dwProcessID As Long
    dwThreadID As Long
End Type

'Added
Private Type SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    nLength As Long
    lpSecurityDescriptor As LongPtr
    bInheritHandle As Long
End Type

Private Declare PtrSafe Function WaitForSingleObject Lib "kernel32" (ByVal _
    hHandle As LongPtr, ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) As Long




'Type not defined
Declare PtrSafe Function CreateProcessA Lib "kernel32" _
    (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, ByVal lpCommandLine As String, _
    lpProcessAttributes As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, lpThreadAttributes As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, _
    ByVal bInheritHandles As Long, ByVal dwCreationFlags As Long, lpEnvironment As Any, _
    ByVal lpCurrentDriectory As String, lpStartupInfo As STARTUPINFO, _
    lpProcessInformation As PROCESS_INFORMATION) As Long
    
' Original
'Private Declare Function CreateProcessA Lib "kernel32" (ByVal _
    lpApplicationName As Long, ByVal lpCommandLine As String, ByVal _
    lpProcessAttributes As Long, ByVal lpThreadAttributes As Long, _
    ByVal bInheritHandles As Long, ByVal dwCreationFlags As Long, _
    ByVal lpEnvironment As Long, ByVal lpCurrentDirectory As Long, _
    lpStartupInfo As STARTUPINFO, lpProcessInformation As _
    PROCESS_INFORMATION) As Long
    
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal _
    hObject As LongPtr) As Long
    
Public Sub ShellWait(Pathname As String, Optional WindowStyle As Long)
    Dim proc As PROCESS_INFORMATION
    Dim start As STARTUPINFO
    Dim ret As Long
    ' Initialize the STARTUPINFO structure:
    With start
        .cb = Len(start)
        If Not IsMissing(WindowStyle) Then
            .dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
            .wShowWindow = WindowStyle
        End If
    End With
    ' Start the shelled application:
    ret& = CreateProcessA(0&, Pathname, 0&, 0&, 1&, _
            NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, 0&, 0&, start, proc) 'TEST SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES Data Types
    ' Wait for the shelled application to finish:
    ret& = WaitForSingleObject(proc.hProcess, INFINITE)     ' TEST proc.hProcess is LongPtr
    ret& = CloseHandle(proc.hProcess)                   ' TEST proc.hProcess is LongPtr
End Sub


Public Function GetExecutableForFile(strFileName As String) As String
   Dim lngRetval As LongPtr
   Dim strExecName As String * 255
   lngRetval = FindExecutable(strFileName, vbNullString, strExecName)
   GetExecutableForFile = Left$(strExecName, InStr(strExecName, Chr$(0)) - 1)
End Function

Sub RunIt(strNewFullPath As String)
   Dim exeName As String

   exeName = GetExecutableForFile(strNewFullPath)
   Shell exeName & " " & Chr(34) & strNewFullPath & Chr(34), vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

I already  tinkered with it from [this](https://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/apideclarations.asp) site by adding **LongPtr** where I believe it should of been. I also added **SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES** type that wasn't in the original code.

I am getting a compile error on the following line under the ShellWait sub:

```
ret& = CreateProcessA(0&, Pathname, 0&, 0&, 1&, _
                NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, 0&, 0&, start, proc)
```

The error is on the third parameter and says: `"ByRef Argument Type Mismatched"`
Originally the SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES were type Long.

If I change back to LongPtr the error is gone, but does not work when I try the command `ShellWait "clac.exe"`

I get no error message when debugging line by line. Nothing happens.
I am testing in 64 bit Access first.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues to tackle here.

First, the API function should return a `LongPtr`. You'll need to change that in your function declare statment. You'll also need to change your `ret` variable to a `LongPtr`.

Second, the reason for the type mismatch is because your parameter value `0&` is not of type `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES`. You must build a `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` type and pass that in as a parameter.

EDIT:
Here is all the code I have in a module that is compiling just fine. Just want to see if I can help understand why you are still getting the compiler error:

```
Option Explicit

'This code was originally written by Terry Kreft.
'It is not to be altered or distributed,
'except as part of an application.
'You are free to use it in any application,
'provided the copyright notice is left unchanged.
'
'Code Courtesy of
'Terry Kreft
Private Const STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW& = &H1
Private Const NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS = &H20&
Private Const INFINITE = -1&

Private Type STARTUPINFO
    cb As Long
    lpReserved As String
    lpDesktop As String
    lpTitle As String
    dwX As Long
    dwY As Long
    dwXSize As Long
    dwYSize As Long
    dwXCountChars As Long
    dwYCountChars As Long
    dwFillAttribute As Long
    dwFlags As Long
    wShowWindow As Integer
    cbReserved2 As Integer
    lpReserved2 As Long
    hStdInput As LongPtr
    hStdOutput As LongPtr
    hStdError As LongPtr
End Type

Private Type PROCESS_INFORMATION
    hProcess As LongPtr
    hThread As LongPtr
    dwProcessID As Long
    dwThreadID As Long
End Type

'Added
Private Type SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    nLength As Long
    lpSecurityDescriptor As LongPtr
    bInheritHandle As Long
End Type

Private Declare PtrSafe Function WaitForSingleObject Lib "kernel32" (ByVal _
    hHandle As LongPtr, ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) As Long




'Type not defined
Declare PtrSafe Function CreateProcessA Lib "kernel32" _
    (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, ByVal lpCommandLine As String, _
    lpProcessAttributes As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, lpThreadAttributes As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, _
    ByVal bInheritHandles As Long, ByVal dwCreationFlags As Long, lpEnvironment As Any, _
    ByVal lpCurrentDriectory As String, lpStartupInfo As STARTUPINFO, _
    lpProcessInformation As PROCESS_INFORMATION) As LongPtr
    
' Original
'Private Declare Function CreateProcessA Lib "kernel32" (ByVal _
    lpApplicationName As Long, ByVal lpCommandLine As String, ByVal _
    lpProcessAttributes As Long, ByVal lpThreadAttributes As Long, _
    ByVal bInheritHandles As Long, ByVal dwCreationFlags As Long, _
    ByVal lpEnvironment As Long, ByVal lpCurrentDirectory As Long, _
    lpStartupInfo As STARTUPINFO, lpProcessInformation As _
    PROCESS_INFORMATION) As Long
    
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal _
    hObject As LongPtr) As Long
    
Public Sub ShellWait(Pathname As String, Optional WindowStyle As Long)
    Dim proc As PROCESS_INFORMATION
    Dim start As STARTUPINFO
    Dim ret As LongPtr
'Not used, but needed
    Dim si1 As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    Dim si2 As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    
    ' Initialize the STARTUPINFO structure:
    With start
        .cb = Len(start)
        If Not IsMissing(WindowStyle) Then
            .dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
            .wShowWindow = WindowStyle
        End If
    End With
'Set the structure size
    si1.nLength = Len(si1)
    si2.nLength = Len(si2)
    ' Start the shelled application:
    ret = CreateProcessA(vbNullString, Pathname, si1, si2, False, _
            NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, 0&, vbNullString, start, proc) 'TEST SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES Data Types
    ' Wait for the shelled application to finish:
    ret = WaitForSingleObject(proc.hProcess, INFINITE)     ' TEST proc.hProcess is LongPtr
    ret = CloseHandle(proc.hProcess)                   ' TEST proc.hProcess is LongPtr
End Sub
```

Comment: I missed the LongPtr in the function. I created the SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES type in the original Post per the link. I still get the error: `"ByRef Argument Type Mismatched"` on `si1`.

Comment: @Rick - I realize you created the `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTE ` type. But, did you declare si1 as a SECURITY_ATTRIBUTE and initialize it using the `si1.nLength = Len(si1)` in your `ShellWait` method? Can you try replacing your entire `ShellWait` method with mine? I donnot get any compiler error on my machine with this solution.

Comment: I substituted the whole function, still get the same error.

Comment: @Rick I updated my answer with the complete module. It doesn't make sense that you are getting a type mismatch and I am not. Hope this can help. if not, I'm sorry and good luck to you :-)

Comment: I substituted all. Not sure what was causing it. I no longer get any errors, but it does nothing when running. `ShellWait "clac.exe", vbNormalNoFocus`

Comment: @Rick for that, I'd have to ask what are you expecting to have happen?

Comment: In this case, just open the calculator application as an example.

Comment: @Rick I too cannot get the calculator to open, though it does seem to start the process. In contrast, running `ShellWait "notepad",1` or `ShellWait "cmd.exe",1` do work... How strange. There must be something different going on with the calculator. Are you running windows 10?

Comment: I am using Windows 10. Opening notepad and cmd works fine.
I tested with calculator since it was just easier, I thought. My original code was to summon cmd and copy a file, which does not work either.

Comment: @Rick interesting. cmd is working for me. Any reason you are doing this though the winAPI instead of just a vba `Shell` method?